# Excel IF Formula in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have the below piece of vba code that doesnt work.

```
Range(C5:C & Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Formula =IF(B4=""X"",'HUB'!$F$5,'HUB'!F$4$)&""-""&""Q""&HUB!B$2$&"" QA""&HUB!C$6$"
```

I think there is sth wrong with the formula and with & sign. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: You need to start with a double quote to start of the string that holds the formula to begin with... `=IF(B4=` is no valid vba syntax. These type of question can be avoided if you'd use `Debug.Print` and try and test what your code would actually print.

Answer (score 0):

`'HUB'!F$4$`
The `$` placement is incorrect.

Change it to `$F$4` and check the other notations ad well; I noticed more of the same.

Comment: Also `"` is missing before `=IF(`

Comment: Hi This I have also changed and still it doesnt work.

Comment: `Range(C5:C &` needs to be `Range("C5:C" &`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding double quotes like this :

[image]